# Sum a column that corresponds a aggregate from a column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions

Sorry about the title, but i couldn't think of a better subject for my issue.

I've two tables in a many-to-one relationship between them and an other many-to-one relatioshop in the same table. I need to sum a column that corresponds a aggregate from a column of first table.

Here is a image that illustrate what i want:

[image: example]
I have no idea how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(E.idParent,E.id) Id,
        SUM(I.Value) [Sum]
FROM EXPENSE_TABLE E
LEFT JOIN INVOICE_TABLE I
    ON I.idExpense = E.id
GROUP BY ISNULL(E.idParent,E.id)
```

For the updated requirement:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(E.idParent,E.id) Id,
        E2.[description],
        SUM(I.Value) [Sum]
FROM EXPENSE_TABLE E
LEFT JOIN INVOICE_TABLE I
    ON I.idExpense = E.id
INNER JOIN EXPENSE_TABLE E2
    ON ISNULL(E.idParent,E.id) = E2.id
GROUP BY ISNULL(E.idParent,E.id),
         E2.[description]
```

Comment: I need to show the description of expense parent too... but if i add the column, an error results. How can i do this?

Comment: @dellasavia Well, the description is different per id on the the expense table, so I don't really know how you want to add that column. Maybe if you show the desired output I can understand what you want

Comment: Please, @Lamak, help-me with other question too: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008870/sum-two-columns-that-corresponds-a-agregate-from-a-columns-of-two-tables#comment28088397_19009799). Is related with this question.

Comment: +1, my answer would be the same except I'd use an inner join instead of the left join, because parent rows in `EXPENSE_TABLE` do not appear to have data in `INVOICE_TABLE`. As a result, I wouldn't need ISNULL either. (I realise, though, that people sometimes provide incomplete data samples, so I would also stipulate all my assumptions in my answer.)

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, I was assuming that if maybe an expense doesn't have a child one, then it may only appear once without a parent

Comment: Yes, since all the rows are in the same table, nothing prevents you from referencing a parent row instead of a child one. Makes perfect sense, actually more than my assumption does, as I based it on the *contents* of an example, while you made yours based on the *design*.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results you are looking for by performing the aggregate sum operation on the results of the EXPENSE_TABLE joined to the INVOICE_TABLE.

For example:

```
SELECT e.idParent, SUM(i.value)
FROM EXPENSE_TABLE AS e
INNER JOIN INVOICE_TABLE AS i ON i.idExpense = e.id
GROUP BY e.idParent
ORDER BY e.idParent
```