# Sum two columns that corresponds a agregate from a columns of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Yesterday I posted a question on which said sum of columns of a table. [See here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990927/sum-a-column-that-corresponds-a-aggregate-from-a-column-of-another-table)

However, I got into some other complications. I have a second table that needs to have a column added in correspondence with the first.

Here's what I need:

[image: diagram]

The column 'sum2' is new and I am not able to sum it correctly!

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Are you trying to group by idParent, or idExpense? There is only 1 row for each idExpense, so there is no need for aggregation.

Comment: i'm trying to group by idParent, in the other question quoted, there is a query sended by @Lamak that works perfectly when only one agregation is needed.

Comment: If you copied the text of your sample above it'd be easier than the image, even better would be to set up the tables on [SQLFiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3)  How do you put links in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the issue is, without seeing your code.  I built a small sample in SQLFIddle:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1977c)

It's giving me the same result as you have in your post:

```
IDPARENT    COLUMN_1    COLUMN_2
1            28.25          9.5
```